# Is HTTPClient now caching responses in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have an Angular 7 app `v7.2.10` and `rxjs v6.3.3`. I' puzzled about a behavior I'm seeing with the HTTPClient whereby I can see it keeps track of performed requests. Not sure if that's new or, strangely due to a side effect of my code. In essence I have a service that does:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class AvailabilityService {

        constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

        public getMonthAvailability(year: number, month: number): Promise<IMonthAvailability> {
            console.log('hit');
            return this.http.get<IMonthAvailability>(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/availability/${year}/${month}`)
                            .toPromise()
                            .then(r => {
                               console.log('response');
                               return r;
                            })
                            .catch((error: Response | any) => {
                                return Promise.reject(error);
                            });
        }
    }
```

so I get back an `IMonthAvailability` given the `month` and the `year`. That response is currently integrated on a calendar and all works fine. The data is being retrieved from a .NET Core API which I now have specified (don't think I need it though because it hasn't made any difference) `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store` just in case. The response headers:

```
Date →Wed, 03 Apr 2019 15:46:57 GMT
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Server →Kestrel
Cache-Control →no-store, no-cache
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
```

I'm assuming is all fine with the setup. In fact I haven't seen this before. So what happens is that when I move the calendar month and I go to the next month I can see the API being hit and the data is retrieved. If I now go back to a previous month that I already had loaded up, the promise is automatically resolved and the data "is somehow already there" and the API is not being called. My question is whether due to the speed of the call, whether Angular keeps track of really fast calls /with small payload or is that something completely independent...Like I say, I have built other APIs and clients in Angular and never saw this.

Any explanation/tip is really appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I have added the following console.log statements to the parts of the method I think should be hit and I can see both of them being logged ALL THE TIME.

Comment: My guess is that you've stored the returned promise somehow. Add a console.log() statement to your method and see if it's being called again or not. Chek your browser network panel.

Comment: I have added a console.log('hit!) right before the return statement and I can see this being written in the console so that's definitely being called. I have added another console.log to the then part and it's also being run

Comment: I have updated the example code with the logs I added as you suggested

Comment: Then check your network panel of the browsr dev tools. If it says that the response comes from the cache, then it's a browser caching issue. If not, your server does some caching, or it's indeed called and you're not seeing it somehow.

Comment: Yeah, did that as well, I couldn't find in the network list the call being made the second time if that makes sense. The server is definitely not being hit

Comment: Then you probably have an interceptor somewhere that does the caching. HttpCLient doesn't do that by itself.

Comment: Just went through the entire APP and found the problem: TransferHttpCacheModule . removing that it solves the issue. I was supposed to add the BrowserTransferStateModule for SSR however I added that by mistake instead